# managing html rich text selections

Tags: javascript, html, xml, richtextbox, selection

I am writing a component for a web app which will display some html, and let me capture and manipulate the selection boundaries (of the text selected by the user). I have done this successfully (for Mozilla) with a simple div element using window.getSelection(). However, the browser selection API is different for IE.

If I were to use a textarea instead (for interacting with the selection api), is there a uniform API across the browsers? Then I would need to overlay a DIV on top of this to display the styled text, and presumably I'd need to manage the cursor etc...

Basically I want a rich text editor - but without editing. Does anyone have any advice on the best way to go about this, which is quick, simple and cross browser compatible. I don't want to spend ages reinventing the wheel...

(If anyone's interested - this is for an online xml editor. I capture the users selection on a html version of the xml doc and then send the selection offsets info to the server, where the real xml doc gets marked up).

Kind Regards

Swami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a textarea won't help: the API is not consistent there either. I'd suggest using [IERange](http://code.google.com/p/ierange/) to get a consistent API for selections.

Comment: Thanks Tim - Exactly what I needed to know. Great link.